# Cannot create a project in modelsim

Tags: modelsim

I've downloaded Modelsim from this website (https://fpgasoftware.intel.com/?product=modelsim_ae#tabs-2) to be specific I downloaded the ModelSim-Intel FPGA Started Edition Part 1 and 2.AFter installing I went to create a project and this is the error I get;

[image]

I have never worked with Modelsim or anything similiar so Im not sure why this is happening.Any insights?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow,that worked just fine,thank you Joe! If you could make your comment into an answer I could upvote you and mark the question as solved,to not cause any more commotion.